# I can't add images in my android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add an image in my android project. I do the following, right click res->Add->Image Asset and choose "Action Bar and Tab Icons". Then I import my image but it doesn't appear.

[In this screenshot you can see i have added the image but it isn't appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R6nb.png)

Comment: Does the image asset appear in your Drawable folders HDPI, etc?

Comment: You should add the image asset to drawable folder by right clicking on it not on res folder.The asset may have already been added to the res folder at the bottom you can find it by changing the directory structure from `android` to `project` at the top left in `projects pane`

Comment: copy your images to res->drawable folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a easy way to import images is the Batch Drawable import. For this you need to install a plugin. Check this source. Hope it helps

http://www.javahelps.com/2015/02/android-drawable-importer.html

Comment: I also had the same problem of adding a jpg image of 1.5MB size into drawable. This plugin worked. What i did : Drawable (right click)-> New -> MultiSource Drawable and I add same image path for all options.

Answer (score 3):

Use png images (not PNG) and drag and drop (or copy and paste) into res>drawable. Be aware the name of the files does not contain any number because it gave problems to me.

Comment: This solved my issue, I had images with numbers as names, AS is weird

Answer (score 3):

Copy the image and paste it into the res(maybe in drawable).There should be no capital letters because it will crash.Then create an image view,give an id to the image view and display your pic with a button for example onClick.

```
nameOfImageView.setImageViewDrawabλε(getDrawble(R.drawble.nameOfPicture));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide png images only, its name shouldn't contains capital letters or dashes(-).
You can copy the image and paste it in the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but on Visual Studio when using Xamarin. I dunno if my solution will work but I guess it's at least worth a try.

**Possible Solution:**
Stop debugging / put off your emulator before trying to add a new image.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a capital letter in the name of it, always use small letters
I couldn't drag&drop the image so I went on right-click- Add to design and then it was transferred